# Localize date format in Laravel

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am using Laravel 5.2 with Carbon and I trying to get dates in locale format. I mean if I have the date `2015-12-31` in the database, I want it to be printed as `12/31/2015` or `31/12/2015` depends on the user locale.

In the `User` model I have an attribute `locale` that presents the user locale. But I don't know who to make it works. I know that Laravel using Carbon for dates, but in the Carbon class I see that the format `Y-m-d` is hard coded.

I still need the dates will be saved in format `Y-m-d` and only the presentation will depends on the `User->locale` attribute.

So how can I achieve that behavior? Is there any way to do that with Carbon itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this using `Carbon` but it seems like it's really going to vary according to the specs of your server and what not. From reading, it seems like locale packages aren't always consistent. Use `locale -a` on your production server terminal to check which supported locales you have installed. If you need to install one, use `sudo locale-gen <NEW LOCALE>`.

But once you have your locale strings sorted out, it seems that you can say

```
$date = new Carbon;

setlocale('en_GB');

echo $date->formatLocalized('%x'); // '16/06/16'
```

I derived the `%x` modifier from the `strftime()` function, it specifies the format to be "the preferred date representation based on locale, without the time" according to [the php manual](http://php.net/strftime)

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for you.
Override `getAttribute` method in your model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use DateFormatting;

    protected $dates = [
        'finished_at',
        // other field names that you need to format
    ];

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $this->getDates() ) ) {
           // here you can format your date
        }
        return parent::getAttribute($key);
    }

}
```

after all you can access to this fields as usual(using magic `__get()`)

```
$model->finished_at;
```